# Etiquetas de las cuestiones migradas a Meta: usar "discusión" en lugar de "discussion"

Tags: bug, etiquetas, meta, migración

Hace un rato observé que una pregunta fue migrada del sitio principal a Meta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388/stackoverflow-la-peor-comunidad . Mirando el [historial de revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1388/revisions) observé que inicialmente tenía la etiqueta [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Por lo que veo esta es la norma de etiquetaje en caso de migraciones:

> Si una pregunta no tiene ninguna etiqueta en común con el sitio al que se intenta migrar la migración se rechaza, a menos que:
>
> - Se migre a Meta, en cuyo caso se etiqueta automáticamente con [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).
> - La migre un moderador, en cuyo caso se etiqueta automáticamente con [untagged](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).
> - Use una [etiqueta intrínseca](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215921/209901) (parecida, vaya), en cuyo caso también se la etiqueta con [untagged](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).
>
> <sub>Fuente: [What happens to the tags when a question is migrated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341609/1983854)</sub>

El caso que nos ocupa es el primero, en cuyo caso la etiqueta debe ser [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). Sin embargo, hace unos días que las etiquetas de Meta se tradujeron al español ([listado aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest)), por lo que en lugar de [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) ahora aquí usamos [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) (con tilde y una *s*). Además, la inglesa figura como sinónima de la castellana.
A pesar de ello, al migrar una pregunta desde el sitio principal a Meta el reetiquetaje no se realizó y se le asignó [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) en lugar de [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n).

¿Sería posible cambiar el proceso que etiqueta las preguntas migradas para que etiquete correctamente con la etiqueta con nombre español?

Comment: Más allá de que sería bueno que se haga directamente en la migración, agrego un comentario aparte (no es la solución, pero quizás es para tener en cuenta): siendo un sinónimo, me pregunto si no hay un proceso que se dispara periódicamente para corregirlo... creo recordar que en otro caso, demoró 24hs aprox en corregir un sinónimo.

Comment: @Mariano mmm curioso, no conozco el proceso que mencionas. En principio los reetiquetajes son inmediatos.

Comment: Es cierto para el caso general, pero me refiero a un caso donde la etiqueta existe antes de generar el sinónimo... No sé si aplica o no ese mismo proceso, pero lo comenté porque quizás era para tener en cuenta (más allá de que no sea una solución directa al bug que estás planteando).

Comment: @Mariano ajá, entiendo. A ver si Konaniman pasa por aquí y nos saca de dudas :)

Comment: También pasa en SOpt: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6098/empregos-e-imprimir-perfil-pdf

Comment: Reportado en Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310776/209901

Answer (score 2):

Añado esta respuesta para llamar la atención sobre este tema, ya que al parecer sigue sucediendo. Ejemplo de hoy mismo: [Cómo se pueden mandar mensajes privados en stackOverflow?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3384/15301)