# Cómo se pueden mandar mensajes privados en stackOverflow?

Tags: discusión, chat

Hay alguna manera en esta página de mandar un mensaje privado a un usuario, o abrir una sala de chat con el mismo?

Comment: Un mensaje privado no se puede. Pero para la sala de chat, mira la pregunta enlazada. Un saludo